# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error in Django Register function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I was trying to do Register and Login form but I am taking "'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'" error. How can I solve this error. And also if you have suggestion for better code writing or better way for this form I would be happy. Here is my views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import RegisterationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login as dj_login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import logout as dj_logout


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = {
                "username" : form.cleaned_data["username"],
                "email" : form.cleaned_data["email"],
                "password1" : form.cleaned_data["password1"],
                "password2" : form.cleaned_data["password2"]
            }
            user = form.save()
            dj_login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,"Kayıt İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir.")
            return redirect("index")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Kayıt İşlemi Sırasında Bir Hata Meydana Geldi.")
            return render(request,"register.html",context={"RegisterForm":form})
    else:
        form = RegisterationForm()
        return render(request,"register.html",context={"RegisterForm":form})
```

And here is my register.html file.

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
Register
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>Register</h1>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{RegisterForm.username.label}}
        {{RegisterForm.username}}
        <br><br>
        {{RegisterForm.email.label}}
        {{RegisterForm.email}}
        <br><br>
        {{RegisterForm.password1.label}}
        {{RegisterForm.password1}}
        <br><br>
        {{RegisterForm.password2.label}}
        {{RegisterForm.password2}}
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit">Kayıt Ol</button>

    </form>
{% endblock body %}
```

and this is my error.

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/users/register/

Django Version: 4.1.2
Python Version: 3.10.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main',
'crispy_forms',
'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\My Projects\My-Site\blog\users\views.py", line 22, in register
    dj_login(request,user)
File "C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 138, in login
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
File "C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 268, in inner
    return func(_wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/register/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

and this is my RegisterationForm:

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegisterationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username","email","password1","password2"]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]

        if commit : 
            user.save()
        else:
            return user
```

Comment: Share your `RegisterationForm`,

Comment: I've shared.  I hope you can help me.